# Using `this` keyword in plain C

Tags: c++, c

I am used to program in C++. I like the Object Oriented stuff and the like the language provides.
But now I have to program in plain C, since I have to use an embedded system without support for C++ compiler, only plain C.

I want to keep usign "Object Oriented" functions, thus I usually write my modules like this:

```
//Maybe hidden with PIMPL...
typedef struct myModuleData_
{
}myModuleData;

myModuleData* moduleCreate();
void moduleFree(myModuleData *this_);

void moduleSetSomething(myModuleData *this_, int something);
```

Now my question is: can I replace `this_` with `this` (without the final underscore)? Will the usage of `this` in plain C interfere in the future with C++ if I use this module in C++ by using it with extern "C"?

Comment: Remove `this` from the functions declaration, make sure the module *itself* is always compiled with a C compiler, and you will have no issue with using `this` as the identifier for the object inside the module.

Comment: Also, [don't typedef the struct away](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html)

Comment: You could also use `self`, which is commonly used on other languages when you need explicit `this`.

Comment: Why not `_this` but `this_`? Is it better to see `this_->member`.

Comment: @StoryTeller That post is subjective nonsense. The vast majority of the programmers around the world prefer to use typedef. This is particularly true for C++ programmers or programmers mixing C and C++. The Linux world prefer not to use typedef, for subjective, irrational reasons. It is a matter of style completely. There is no need to preach one style before the other here, especially not when dealing with beginners.

Comment: @i486 - The C and C++ standard have a bunch of hard to remember rules about reserved identifier when it comes to a leading underscore. Many just prefer not to open that can of worms and avoid leading underscores.

Comment: @Lundin - "irrational reasons" now there's some subjective nonsense if I've ever heard such a thing. One may not like the Linux coding guidelines, but to say they have absolutely no basis in reason is bogus. That awful typedefing practice is the cause of more then one beginner question on SO that asks "why can't I forward declare this?".

Comment: It took me about 5 minutes to write a test program that confirms you can't use `this` as a parameter name in a header you include in a C++ program.

Comment: @StoryTeller The Linux kernel coding style guide is overall an amateur-level document, lacking sources, scientific proof and rationales. This whole thing is a known style war between Linux fans and the rest of the C programming world. We don't need style wars here.

Comment: @Lundin - I daresay the first inflammatory rhetoric came from you. I merely suggested what I consider a good practice that prevents a certain class of errors for the price of some syntactic sugar.

Comment: @StoryTeller Linus is wrong. Well, he might be right with respect to the Linux kernel where resources are scarce, but there is nothing wrong with type abstraction in general terms.

Comment: @StoryTeller *Also, [don't typedef the struct away](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html)* On a Centos 6 server I have access to, `find /usr/include -name \*.h | xargs grep typedef | grep struct | wc -l` returns 8042. Even running that in `/usr/include/linux` returns 191. Seems Linus doesn't follow his own "rule"...

Comment: @JeremyP - This isn't a type abstraction, this is namespace hiding syntactic sugar IMO. Regardless, the point is moot. I said my piece, you guys said yours.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Linus isn't the sole contributer to the kernel. He accepts huge patches from people he trusts that are less stringent then him in regard to the patches *they* accept. Happens.

Comment: @StoryTeller I used "type abstraction" only because Linus himself referred to it as that in the post to which you linked.

Comment: @StoryTeller So, Linus's standard on `typedef` of structures is a mere subjective preference that he doesn't even bother to enforce?  Your comment is based on the unenforced style preference of one person?

Comment: @JeremyP - And he didn't object to it in general terms. So, yeah... flame wars...

Comment: @AndrewHenle The files in `/usr/include` define APIs that are out of Linus's control. You can't use them to beat him over the head with.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - My comment is based on the fact people are imperfect, and Linus being practical and pragmatic from time to time. Why do you insist on dragging this on, btw? What are you hoping to win?

Comment: @JeremyP In an appeal to authority as a logical argument, demonstrating that the authority *explicitly picked to support the argument* doesn't even bother to enforce the argument's position shows that the "authority" isn't one.  Because not only are the ones in `/usr/include/kernel` under Linus's control, many of those 8,000+ others are too. FWIW, the RH kernel source tree yields a count of `typedef struct` of over 900...

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I didn't appeal to authority, I linked to someone else's colorful explanation of my approach so as to avoid repeating it verbatim by myself. Next time consider asking if I linked solely because it's "Linus Torvalds" who said it or because I agree with the content. As my comments to Jeremy clearly indicate, it's the latter.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am on your side with regard to the general point, I merely objected to your use of the files in /usr/include as evidence of Linus's inconsistency when the vast majority of them were written by people working on other projects and the contents of many are mandated by standards e.g. C11, POSIX. It is legitimate to do the exercise on the Linux kernel source tree, but that is not what you did in the first instance. Anyway, we are all agreed that the typedefs are fine in the general case, even Linus agrees that according to StoryTeller.

Comment: @JeremyP - Yup. I don't know how I'd code without the typedefs in `stdint.h`.

Comment: Any C programmer can take a quick glimpse at the actual Linux kernel source code. After which you'll immediately dismiss both Torvalds and the Linux kernel coding document as any form of C authorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that since `this` is a reserved word in C++. It cannot be used as the name of an ordinary argument.

You can remove the name from the header and keep it in the C file, but that of course means making the header slightly worse since it no longer contains the hint what that argument is meant for.

Comment: Ok, understood. I will use `self` as somebody has stated in another comment.

Comment: @LoPiTaL `self` is the equivalent of `this` in Objective-C. However, it is not a reserved word so much as just an implicitly defined argument so you won't run into the same issues.